# *ngIf only if it matches a value in an array in firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working in Firestore, I try to show an image only if the uid of the user matches a value of a Array. Can someone give me an idea of how to do it?

So far I have been able to do it but with a string and it works well:
[image]

```
<div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
  <img *ngIf="evento.favoritos2 === user.uid " src="assets/icons/Icon_bookmark02.svg" alt="iconFavorito">
</div>
```

But in the case of an Array, how would it be?
[image]

I tried this but it did not work:

```
<div *ngIf="auth.user | async as user">
  <img *ngIf="evento.indexOf(favoritos) === user.uid " src="assets/icons/Icon_bookmark02.svg" alt="iconFavorito">
</div>
```

Comment: Whats the value of evento? indexOf returns the index as number. So number === string is always false. Also you can not pass an array to indexOf.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the favoritos array contains the user id you could use the find method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

But you can not use array methodes inside a `*ngIf` directive.

You have to subscribe to your auth observable inside your component.ts file.

**Here an example:**

component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.subscribe( user => {
        this.user = user;
        this.showImage = this.evento.favoritos.find(element => element === user.uid);
    }
}
```

component.html

```
div *ngIf="user">
<img *ngIf="showImage" src="assets/icons/Icon_bookmark02.svg" alt="iconFavorito">
</div>
```

I do not know your exact code, so you maybe have to modify the code a little. And do not forget to unsubscribe inside `ngOnDestroy`.

Comment: I tried but I get the following error: `Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 33 in [evento.favoritos.find(element => element === user.uid)] in @78:29Angular`

Comment: My bad, you can not use array methods inside a `*ngIf`. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The indexOf() method searches the array for the specified item and returns its position and not **True/False**

**favoritos** is an array and you are checking index of on **evento**

```
  <img *ngIf="evento.favoritos.indexOf(user.uid) !== -1" src="assets/icons/Icon_bookmark02.svg" alt="iconFavorito">
```